# AJAX admin Internal 500 error Failed to Upload

Tags: ajax, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, buddypress

I have a plugin to fetch information user from wpdb. After minor update security Wordpress 4.8.2, plugin did not run well. My sellect button can not run and open data to the table.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_batch_course_stats',array($this,'get_batch_course_stats'));
```

This line if I put outside the class, it run but can not fetch the data because my query inside the class.

This is my code.

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPLMS_BATCH_STATISITCS_SLUG' ) )
        define( 'WPLMS_BATCH_STATISITCS_SLUG', 'stats' );

if ( class_exists( 'BP_Group_Extension' ) ) :

    class BP_Group_Course_Batch_Statistics extends BP_Group_Extension {

        var $message;

        function __construct() { 

            $args = array(
                'slug' => WPLMS_BATCH_STATISITCS_SLUG,
                'name' => __( 'Statistics', 'wplms-batches' ),
                'visibility'        => 'private',
                'nav_item_position' => 10,
                'enable_nav_item' => false,
                'screens' => array(
                    'admin' => array(
                        'metabox_context'  => 'side',
                        'metabox_priority' => 'core'
                    ),
                    'create' => array(
                        'enabled' => false,
                    ),
                    'edit' => array(
                        'enabled' => false,
                    ),
                )
            );
            $group_id = bp_get_group_id();
            global $wpdb, $bp;
            if(isset($bp->groups) && is_object($bp->groups->current_group)){
                $enable = groups_get_groupmeta($bp->groups->current_group->id, 'course_batch' );
            }else{
                $enable = 0;
            }

            if(!empty($enable)){
                $args['enable_nav_item'] = true;
            }

            $flag = 1;
            if(isset($bp->groups) && is_object($bp->groups->current_group)){
                $batch_stats_visibility = groups_get_groupmeta($bp->groups->current_group->id,'batch_stats_visibility');
            }


            if(!empty($batch_stats_visibility)){
                $user_id = get_current_user_ID();
                if($batch_stats_visibility == 'mods'){
                    if(!groups_is_user_mod($user_id,$bp->groups->current_group->id)){
                        $flag = 0; 
                    }
                }else if($batch_stats_visibility == 'admins'){
                    if(!groups_is_user_admin($user_id,$bp->groups->current_group->id)){
                        $flag = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($flag){
                parent::init( $args );
                add_action('wplms_batch_statistics',array($this,'batch_statistics'),10,1);
                add_action('wplms_batch_moderator_statistics',array($this,'moderator_statistics'),10,1);             
                 add_action('wp_ajax_get_batch_course_stats', array($this,'get_batch_course_stats'));
                add_action('bp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'cssjs' ) );


            }



        }



            function cssjs(){
                    if( bp_is_single_item() && bp_is_groups_component() && bp_is_current_action(WPLMS_BATCH_STATISITCS_SLUG) ){
                    wp_enqueue_script('datatables-js',plugins_url( '/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'));
                    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-datatables-js',plugins_url( '/assets/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__ ));
                        }
                        }




        /**
         * display() contains the markup that will be displayed on the main 
         * plugin tab
         */
        function display( $group_id = NULL ) {

            if(empty($group_id))
                $group_id = bp_get_group_id();


            do_action('wplms_batch_statistics',$group_id);
            if(bp_current_user_can( 'bp_moderate' )){
                do_action('wplms_batch_moderator_statistics',$group_id);
            }else{
                do_action('wplms_batch_student_statistics',$group_id);
            }

            $leaderboard = groups_get_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_leaderboard');
            if(bp_current_user_can( 'bp_moderate' ) || !empty($leaderboard)){
                //echo '<h3 class="heading"><span>'._x('Leaderboard','Batch Leaderboard','wplms-batches').'</span></h3>';
                $members = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_member_ids($group_id);
                $courses = groups_get_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_course',false);
                if(empty($courses)){
                    echo '<div class="message">'.__('No Courses connected to Batch','wplms-batches').'</div>';
                    return;
                }
                $member_ids = implode(',',$members);
                $course_ids = implode(',',$courses);
                $course_status_string = '';
                foreach($courses as $c){
                    $course_status_string .= "'course_status".$c."',";
                }
                $course_status_string =trim($course_status_string, ",");
                global $wpdb,$bp;
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT p.meta_key as uid,sum(p.meta_value) as sum 
                    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} as p
                    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} as u
                    ON p.meta_key = u.user_id
                    WHERE p.meta_key IN ($member_ids) 
                    AND p.post_id IN ($course_ids) 
                    AND u.meta_key IN ($course_status_string)
                    AND u.meta_value > %d
                    GROUP BY uid ORDER BY sum DESC",3));
                ?>

    <?php

            }
        }


        function batch_statistics($group_id){
            $courses = groups_get_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_course',false);
            if(empty($courses)){
                echo '<div class="message">'.__('No Courses connected to Batch','wplms-batches').'</div>';
                return;
            }
            $members = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_member_ids($group_id);
            $admins = groups_get_group_admins( $group_id );
            $mods = groups_get_group_mods( $group_id );


            global $wpdb,$bp;
            $batch_average = $batch_badge_count = $batch_certificate_count = 0;
            $batch_average = groups_get_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_average');
            $batch_badge_count = groups_get_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_badge_count');
            $batch_certificate_count = groups_get_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_certificate_count');
            global $wpdb, $bp;
            if(isset($_GET['recalculate'])){
                $batch_badge_count = $batch_certificate_count = 0;
                $total_marks = 0;$total_denom = 1;
                foreach($members as $member_id){
                    foreach($courses as $course_id){
                        $status = bp_course_get_user_course_status($member_id,$course_id);
                        if($status > 3){
                            $marks = get_post_meta($course_id,$member_id,true);
                            $total_marks += $marks;
                            $total_denom++;
                        }
                    }
                    $certificates = get_user_meta($member_id,'certificates',true);
                    $badges = get_user_meta($member_id,'badges',true);
                    if(!empty($certificates)){
                        foreach($certificates as $certificate_course_id){
                            if(in_array($certificate_course_id,$courses)){
                                $batch_certificate_count++;
                            }
                        }    
                    }
                    if(!empty($badges)){
                        foreach($badges as $badges_course_id){
                            if(in_array($badges_course_id,$courses)){
                                $batch_badge_count++;
                            }
                        }    
                    }
                }
                if($total_denom > 1){
                    $total_denom--;
                }
                $batch_average = round($total_marks/$total_denom,2);
                groups_update_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_average',$batch_average);
                groups_update_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_badge_count',$batch_badge_count);
                groups_update_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_certificate_count',$batch_certificate_count);
            }





            ?>
<?php /*
 ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="course_stats_form">
                    <h3 class="heading"><span><?php _e('Course Specific Statistics','wplms-batches'); ?></span></h3>
                    <select id="batch_course">
                        <?php
                            foreach($courses as $course){
                                echo '<option value="'.$course.'">'.get_the_title($course).'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php wp_nonce_field('batch_course_security'.$group_id,'batch_course_security'); 
                    echo '<input type="hidden" id="course_batch_id" value="'.$group_id.'" />'; ?>
                    <a id="get_batch_course_stats" class="button">
                        <?php _e('Get Stats','wplms-batches'); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php
        }
        function moderator_statistics($group_id){
            global $wpdb, $bp;
            $courses = groups_get_groupmeta($group_id,'batch_course',false);
            if(empty($courses)){
                echo '<div class="message">'.__('No Courses connected to Batch','wplms-batches').'</div>';
                return;
            }

            ?>

                <?php
            $members = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_member_ids($group_id);

        }

        function get_batch_course_stats(){


            $course_id = $_POST['course_id'];
            $batch_id = $_POST['batch_id'];
            $user_id = get_current_user_ID();
            global $wpdb, $bp;
            if ( !isset($_POST['security']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['security'],'batch_course_security'.$batch_id) || !is_numeric($course_id) || !is_numeric($batch_id)){
                _e('Security check Failed. Contact Administrator.','wplms-batches');
                die();
            }

            echo '<h5>'.sprintf(__('Statistics for Course %s','wplms-batches'),'<a href="'.get_permalink($course_id).'" target="_blank">'.get_the_title($course_id)).'</a></h5>';

            if(function_exists('bp_course_get_curriculum_quizes')){
                global $wpdb, $bp;
                $quiz_ids = bp_course_get_curriculum_quizes($course_id);

                    // Sort Quiz id  
                    sort($quiz_ids);
                    $tlength = count($quiz_ids);
                    for($x = 0; $x < $tlength; $x++);

                        /*
                        $flag = 0;
                        if(!empty($quiz_ids)){
                            $flag++;
                            }
                         */  

                    ?>

                     <table class="course_leaderboard table table-hover table-bordered" id="table_course">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th valign="top">
                                    <?php _e('Student','wplms-batches') ?> <br>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Progression (%)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    QCM terminés
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Sessions terminées
                                </th>
                                <?php

                             //if($flag >= 1){
                                foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
                                    echo '<th><a href="'.get_permalink($quiz_id).'" target="_blank">'.get_the_title($quiz_id).'</a></th>';                          
                                    }
                        //}

                        ?>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <?php
                         $members = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_member_ids($batch_id);

                         $i=1;
                         foreach($members as $member_id){


                             foreach ($courses as $course_id)
                                global $wpdb, $bp;
                                $progress = bp_course_get_user_progress($member_id,$course_id);

                        /*
                         * Process for QCM Value
                         */                     

                         global $wpdb, $bp;
                         $marks=$wpdb->get_results(sprintf("
                         SELECT rel.post_id as id, rel.meta_value as val
                             FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                             LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS rel ON posts.ID = rel.post_id
                             WHERE   posts.post_type   = 'quiz'
                             AND     posts.post_title LIKE '%%QCM'
                             AND     posts.post_status   = 'publish'
                             AND     rel.meta_key   = %d
                             AND     rel.meta_value >= 0
                             ", $member_id)
                         );
                         if (is_array($marks)) {
                             foreach ($marks as $k=>$mark) {
                                 $user_marks[] = $mark->val;
                             }
                         }
                             else {
                                 $user_marks = array();
                             }
                             if (is_array($marks))
                             $value = count($marks);

                             if ( $title )
                             $label = $title;
                             else
                             $label = __('Quizzes Completed', 'wplms-dashboard');

                         if (is_array($user_marks)) {
                             foreach ($user_marks as $i=>$mark){
                                 if ($i<11) {
                                     if (!$i)
                                         $marks_string = $mark;
                                         else
                                         $marks_string .= ','.$mark;
                                 }
                             }  
                         }

                        if (!is_numeric($value))
                         $value = 0;


                         /*
                         * Process for Personality Value
                         */   


                         global $wpdb;
                         $marks=$wpdb->get_results(sprintf("
                         SELECT rel.post_id as id, rel.meta_value as val
                             FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                             LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS rel ON posts.ID = rel.post_id
                             WHERE   posts.post_type   = 'quiz'
                             AND     posts.post_title LIKE '%%Test de Personnalité'
                             AND     posts.post_status   = 'publish'
                             AND     rel.meta_key   = %d
                             AND     rel.meta_value >= 0
                             ", $member_id)
                         );


                         if (is_array($marks)) {
                             foreach ($marks as $k=>$mark) {
                                 $user_marks[] = $mark->val;
                             }
                         }
                             else {
                                 $user_marks = array();
                             }

                         if ( $title )
                             $label2 = $title;
                             else
                             $label2 = __('Personality Tests Completed', 'wplms-dashboard');

                         if (is_array($marks))
                             $value2 = count($marks);

                         if (is_array($user_marks)) {
                             foreach ($user_marks as $i=>$mark){
                                 if ($i<11) {
                                     if (!$i)
                                         $marks_string = $mark;
                                         else
                                         $marks_string .= ','.$mark;
                                 }
                             }  
                         }


                         if (!is_numeric($value2))
                         $value2 = 0;


                         ?>


                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $i ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo bp_core_get_user_displayname($member_id) ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $progress ?> %
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $value ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $value2 ?>
                                    </td>

                                    <?php
                                        //if($flag >= 1){
                                        foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
                                            echo '<td>'.get_post_meta($quiz_id,$member_id,true).'</td>';
                                                }
                                        //}
                                        $sum=0;           
                                        $status = bp_course_get_user_course_status($member_id,$course_id);
                                        if($status > 3){
                                            $marks = get_post_meta($course_id,$member_id, true);
                                            $sum += $marks;
                                            echo '<td>'.$marks.'</td>';    
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<td>'._x('N.A','Marks not available in batch statisitcs leaderboard','wplms-batches').'</td>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                        $i++;
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </tr>

                                <?php }?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!-- END Custom Code KVDC -->
                    <?php
        die();
        } 


    } // END of Class

add_action( 'bp_init','wplms_batch_statistics_register_group_extension'); 
function wplms_batch_statistics_register_group_extension(){ 
    bp_register_group_extension( 'BP_Group_Course_Batch_Statistics' );
}
endif;
```

I use buddypress.
and my wp_enqueue_script it side must be put after wp_enqueue_scripts and login_enqueue_scripts.

Before, Wordpress update, all my function work well!!

**UPDATE**

Here additional code

Comment: You're calling the function as if it is inside the class. array($this,'get_batch_course_stats')  But I don't see that function in the class.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATE:

After I saw an error massage it's all because unsupported operand type error.

```
  $sum += $marks;
```

its because store wrong type of value, I change to

```
  $sum->marks;
```